# Double tap gesture for app

Tags: android, gesture

I want to implement a gesture which is specific to my entire app. I tried implementing below method for double tap gesture.

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener 

@Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {

        return false;
    }
```

But I want a functionality like double tap anywhere inside my app should perform some action. Every view's setOnClickListener should detect only single clicks and if its a double click it should bypass to Activity's OnDoubleTapListener. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the root ViewGroup of your activity layout you can implement the method:

```
    private static final long TIME_INITIAL = -1;
    private static final long TIME_DOUBLE_TAP = 250;

    private long lastTouchTime = TIME_INITIAL;

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        long thisTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (thisTime - lastTouchTime <= TIME_DOUBLE_TAP) {
             // do your magic here. I prefer call the listener
            lastTouchTime = TIME_INITIAL;
        } else {
            lastTouchTime = thisTime;
        }
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```